# Matlab Timed Window To Stop Code Based On User Input

Tags: matlab, timeout, msgbox

I am writing a test function which will be running thru multiple scenarios and at each of these scenarios I would like to ask the user if they would like to continue. If they say no then I will save variables and exit the program. This function should have a timeout at which point the code continues to run with no option to quit until the next scenario starts. My problem is with the timeout.

I have looked into setting up a questdlg, but the only way to set up a timeout seems to be by modifying the questdlg.m file which I can't do (due to logistical reasons).

Creating a message box and stopping the code using uiwait works well, but I do not know how to determine if the user has clicked the OK button or how to make the box disappear after the timeout.

Questions:

How do I determine if the button was pressed in msgbox?

How do I make the msgbox disappear?

Is there another way to ask the user if they would like to stop running the test with a 
timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tough part is your first question.

My first idea (better one is below) was to suggest you check based on time whether the user hit OK or it timed out:

```
tic
hmsg=msgbox('message','title','modal'); 
uiwait(hmsg,5); %wait 5 sec
```

then you check based on time whether the user hit the button or execution proceeded due to timeout:

```
if toc < 5 %then the user hit the button before timeout
%no need to close the msgbox  (user already did that)
%appropriate code here...

else %we got here due to timeout
close(hmsg); %close the msgbox
%appropriate code here
end;
```

There is a small risk that you could get an error if they hit the timeout right at the wire and it tries to close a window that is already closed.  If this becomes a problem, I think you can test for whether the handle is valid with:

```
ishandle(hmsg)
```

prior to attempting to close.

Here is I think a **better way**:

```
hmsg=msgbox('message','title','modal');
uiwait(hmsg,5); %wait 5 sec

%now check to see if hmsg is still a handle to find out what happened
if ishandle(hmsg) %then the window is still open (i.e. timeout)
   disp('timeout');
   close(hmsg);
   %appropriate code here...
else %then they closed the window
   disp('user hit button');
   %other code here
end;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the tag? Also there must be a tic placed somewhere before the toc or an error will occur (I am assuming this would be the line before the uiwait).

Comment: sorry - I had gotten half way to a better solution and was stuck before. I edited the answer so that it works with the time method [tic needs to happen before msgbox(....,'modal')], but also gives a better way to assess user input. cheers!